# cobrir background pelo eixo Y

Tags: css, background

Queria saber, se existe alguma forma de a imagem do `background-image` utilizar a propriedade `background-size:cover;` seguindo o eixo vertical.

```
.i-church{
    background-image: url(../../img/icones/Church.png);
    background-size: cover;
    height: 19px;
}
```

Comment: O cover segue os 2 eixos sempre, é a única razão dele existir. Se quer o vertical só, não é cover. Ponha 100% no vertical, e auto no horizontal.

Comment: Seria bom [edit] a pergunta e explicar o efeito que você quer obter, para evitar o pessoal investir tempo em respostas dependendo de chute, que de repente não te sirvam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom pelo o que eu entendi, você está querendo usar o contain?
O cover ele sempre vai seguir os dois eixos, assim que a altura e largura da imagem de background, forem maior ou igual a do container, ele para. o container SEMPRE vai ficar preenchido!

Já o contain, faz com a imagem fique sempre aparecendo por inteira dentro do container. ele não preenche todo o espaço do container caso as dimensões não forem iguais.

Montei aqui um exemplo declarando as duas.

```css
p, div, section{
  float:left;
}

section{
  width:100%; margin-bottom:20px;
}

div {
  border:1px solid #000;
  width:100px; height:100px;
  background:url(https://unsplash.it/90/150/?random) center no-repeat;
}

.cover {
  background-size:cover
}
.contain {
  background-size:contain
}
```

```html
<section><p>Background Normal: </p> <div></div></section>
<section><p>Background Cover: </p> <div class="cover"></div></section>
<section><p>Background Contain: </p> <div class="contain"></div></section>
```

Esperto ter ajudado

Comment: Então, eu só vi agora, eu usei o contain, e ele cobriu pela vertical da forma que eu queria :3 mas obrigado mesmo assim cara, testei o seu aq e tbm funcionou